# I Want to get 2 types of Events, that are, Past Events and Future Events from my Events Model in a Debating Society Website made using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have made a Website for the Debating Society of our College using `Django`.

I would like to have 2 types of events Past and Upcoming (Future) according to the date_of_competition, i.e., if the date and time of competition is past current date and time then return it in past events, and if the date and time of competition is in future of the current date and time then return it in future events

Here are my `views.py` file and `models.py` file for events

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models


class Format(models.Model):
    format_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.format_name


class Organiser(models.Model):
    organiser_name = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organiser_name


class Event(models.Model):
    banner_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="events")
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    organiser_of_event = models.ForeignKey(Organiser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    format_of_event = models.ForeignKey(Format, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_event = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    registration_fees = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="Enter Registration Fees For The Event in Rupees")
    details = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

`view.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Event


# Create your views here.
def events(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'Events',
        'events': Event.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'main/Events.html', context)
```

What logic should be written in order to get both future and past events from my events table?

(If there's anything you don't understand or need something extra, feel free to ask for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way is to just do two queries, using the `__gte` (greater than or  equal) and `__lt` (less than) operators.

```
from django.utils import timezone

# ...

now = timezone.now()

context = {
    'title': 'Events',
    'future_events': Event.objects.filter(date_of_event__gte=now),
    'past_events': Event.objects.filter(date_of_event__lt=now),
}
```

You could also do a single query and do the filtering in Python:

```
now = timezone.now()
all_events = Event.objects.all()
future_events = [e for e in all_events if e.date_of_event >= now]
past_events = [e for e in all_events if e.date_of_event < now]

context = {
    'title': 'Events',
    'future_events': future_events,
    'past_events': past_events,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to overwrite the manager you use for events so you could have Event.past_events.all() and Event.future_events.all()

You could do that with the following:

```
from django.utils import timezone

Class PastEventManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
         today = timezone.now()
         return super().get_queryset().filter(date_of_event__lt=today)

Class Event(models.Model):
    ...
    past_events = PastEventManager()
    future_events = FutureEventManager() # same but with date_of_event__gte=today
```

You can use it in your code like the following:

```
past_events = Event.past_events.all()
future_events = Event.future_events.filter(put_your_query)
```